# Tag merge / synonym request: [Immutable] -> [Immutability]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I prefer immutability but it really doesn't matter. There's no reason to have both tags though, so pick one and stuff the other one inside it. (If you can black-list the alternative might be good afterwards)

Navigate! [immutable](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immutable) [immutability](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immutability)

Comment: There's no need to blacklist the alternative. Once the synonym is set up if anyone tries to use the "wrong" version it will be automatically converted to the "right" one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done.